# SQL Server Compact - connection to SDF data file

Tags: sql-server

I am creating in Visual Studio Express 2012 for web simple CRUD web application (library) as school project. I am inspired by this very nice tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Now I have problem with connection to a SQL Server Compact edition `.sdf` data file.

In `web.config` I have this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LibraryEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\2OBOP3_KU1\R10491\App_Data\R10491_library.sdf;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I created simple ASPX file for database connection testing:

```
<script runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibraryEntities"].ToString()))
      {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Writers", cn);
          cn.Open();
          SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
          rdr.Read();
          Response.Write(rdr[0].ToString()); //read a value
      }
  }
</script>
```

When I run an application it throws an exception:

> *Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)*

But when I try to connect to my `.sdf` file in "Database explorer" tab in "Database Explorer" menu (next to "Solution explorer") I connect successfully.

So I assuming there should be a problem in connection string - isn't it? Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting to a SQL Server Compact not to SQL Server.

You should use `SqlCeConnection` not `SqlConnection`.

```
  using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibraryEntities"].ToString()))
      {
          SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Writers", cn);
          cn.Open();
          SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
          rdr.Read();
          Response.Write(rdr[0].ToString()); //read a value
      }
  }
```

also you need to have a reference to `system.data.sqlserverce.dll`